# How to statically import image for next/image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to statically import an image for use with next/image, but i keep getting an error:

```
./public/IMG_2117.png
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

The `next.config.js` file doesn't have a custom loader or anything - the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader) says that it should work by default/automatically with `next dev` (i.e. no cusom loader necessary) :

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
        imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
    }
}
```

I'm importing the image file like this

```
import Image from "next/image"

import image1 from "../public/IMG_2117.png"
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which Next.js version are you using? Static image imports are supported only on v11 and above.

Comment: @brc-dd thank you, I was using nextjs v10. Since your comment fixed the issue, it should really become an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already put the image in public folder, all you need is to call it directly in the `<Image />` tag like this:

```
      <Image
        src="/IMG_2117.png" // Make sure to put "/" sign 
        alt="A picture"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
```

or if you still want to use the `import image1 from "../public/IMG_2117.png"`, all you need is:

```
      <Image
        src={image1} 
        alt="A picture"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
```

Note: you need to specify the `width` and `height`, if you don't you need to use the `layout` props [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout)

Comment: While this is correct, it is not what I'm looking for - I'd specifically like to statically import the image.

Comment: @Dextication I do believe since you have putted it in the `public` folder, it will automatically serve as a static file. Don't need to add another things (like `.use()` in node) anymore.